# Sending curl when connected to VPN

Tags: http, curl, vpn

After connect to client's through VPN I tried to send curl on http://xx.xxx.x.xx:8089/prod/service (x mean client's IP) but I get "runtime error". It's my first time with VPN and I don't know if the url is wrong or maybe I should do something between connecting VPN and sending curl in terminal?

This is what I get after sending curl:

```
<H1> Server Error in '/prod' Application.<hr width=100% size=1 color=silver></H1>

            <h2> <i>Runtime Error</i> </h2></span>

            <font face="Arial, Helvetica, Geneva, SunSans-Regular, sans-serif ">

            <b> Description: </b>An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.
            <br><br>
```

When I send curl https://google.com it works fine.